# No matching sls found for 'httpd' in env 'base'

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to install and set-up some basic saltstack states.

I am getting the following error when trying to apply a state:
`No matching sls found for 'httpd' in env 'base'`

My setup is as follows:

Centos 7.7.1908

Salt 3000

My directory structure is:
`/etc/salt/srv/salt/httpd.sls`

And my file contains:

```
install_httpd:
  pkg.installed:
    - httpd
```

The command I am running is:

```
salt minion state.sls httpd
```

I have also tried created a top.sls file under:

```
/etc/salt/srv/pillar/top.sls
```

And this file contains:

```
base:
  '*':
    - httpd
```

But I get the same error. However, as far as I am aware, a top.sls file should not be necessary.

Does anyone have any suggestions on this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I found the answer to my own question.

I was assuming that `/srv/salt/` should exist within `/etc/salt/`, which was incorrect. `/srv/salt/` should be its own directory. So if I run `pwd` while inside `/srv/salt/` it looks like this:
`/srv/salt`

If you want to change this so that `/srv/salt` can sit within `/etc/salt/` you will need to adjust your `file_roots` on line 667 of `/etc/salt/master` to be:

```
file_roots:
  base:
    - /etc/salt/srv/salt
```